# {SOLVED} ResponseStatusException not showing error status message in Java RestApi

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, error-handling, httpresponse

I already tried so much way to show the ResponseStatusException only for HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN and HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, cause any status code is shown.

Response that I need, but this response is not showing anything, just blank.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-26T11:51:50.638+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "message",
    "path": "/v1/path"
}
```

I already add `server.error.include-message=always` or use the `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus, reason)` and still not solved.

In this case, I wanna know root of code and how to solve this, Thank you for your answer.

UPDATE, code sample:

```
  @Override
  public SurveyorResponse surveyor(SurveyorRequest request) {
    SurveyorAssignment surveyorAssignment = surveyorAssignmentRepository
      .findBySurveyorIdAndLeadIdAndDeletedIsFalse(request.getSurveyorId(), request.getLeadId())
      .orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "NOT FOUND"));

    List<EmployeeResponse> employeeResponses;

    try {
      employeeResponses = employeeApiClient.getEmployeeByEmpNo(apiKey, List.of(request.getSurveyorId()));

      if (request.getSurveyorId().equals(employeeResponses.get(0).getEmpNo())) {
        log.info("Valid ID");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.info("Not Valid ID");
      throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Not Valid ID");
    }

    boolean validation = identityService.checkPassword(request.getSurveyorId(), request.getPassword());

    if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(validation)) {
      log.info("Not Match");
      throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Not Match");
    } else {
      log.info("Match");

      if (!surveyorAssignment.getAssignmentType().equals("WalkIn")) {
        log.info("Wrong Type");
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "Wrong Type");
      } else {
        log.info("Right");
        return SurveyorResponse
          .builder()
          .surveyorId(employeeResponses.get(0).getEmpNo())
          .Name(employeeResponses.get(0).getEmpName())
          .build();
      }
    }
  }
```

Only for HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST and HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND are showing the response body that I need, FORBIDDEN and UNAUTHORIZED are not shown, but when I change it "FORBIDDEN and UNAUTHORIZED" to the others like BAD_GATEWAY or any, it shows perfectly.

[SOLVED]

Just add .antMatchers("/error").permitAll() in SecurityConfig.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried this far and the results this produced? Also, seeing how you get the response in the first place would help.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of the code you have tried so far? It would be helpful in order to provide u an accurate response

Comment: I already add the sample of code, maybe there's any dependency with the spring version

Comment: Try implementing a ControllerExceptionHandler to add custom exception responses.  Here's a good tutorial you could use as guide and adapt to your needs: https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler/